# JS Charts/Graphs Library that plays well with AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, graphs, charts, angularjs

I'm looking for a javascript Charts / Graphs Library that plays well with AngularJS. It doesn't have to be free.

I intend to implement mainly line graphs, however with some sophistication so they should be highly customizable (e.g. synchronized graphs, multiple y axes, include both lines and separate points in the same graph, handle up to 10k points...)

Highcharts seems like a very good library but it's jquery based. It has this wrapper: https://github.com/pablojim/highcharts-ng, but it says there that "Due to many equality checks the directive maybe slow with large datasets".

Other options that I'm considering:

- ZingChart
- FusionCharts
- Google Charts
- NVD3
- nv-charts

I'm open to more options...

Comment: How about http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/?

Comment: Thanks! Chart.js does look like an eye-candy lib, but their API seems very thin compared to the rich possibilities other libs expose. I know that in the feature I'll need something complex that they don't support.

Comment: D3js is probably the most powerful/popular free JS library, so a wrapper for that would be ideal (https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery). I found https://www.dashingd3js.com/d3-resources/d3-and-angular Let's look for others.  And please see also my question http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/21614/angularjs-charting-with-treemap-and-heatmasp-would-eb-nice

Comment: D3 is indeed powerful, but you practically have to draw almost everything yourself. For my needs there's no reason not to use an existing library - although I need many features, there's no feature that is not implemented one way or another by existing libraries.

Comment: I decided to start off with a Highcharts PoC. Will post here on the results.

Answer (score 5):

ZingChart does have it's own AngularJS directive : https://github.com/zingchart/ZingChart-AngularJS

It has three avenues of injecting data into a chart, each with their own performance cost and functionality benefit. I outlined each of them here : http://www.zingchart.com/blog/2015/03/05/zingchart-angularjs/ .

I'm on the ZingChart team and happened to create the directive so feel free to reach out if you have any questions.

Comment: Since the question is tagged gratis, I have to point out that Zing is only free if you brand your charts, which not everyone may want to.  More at https://www.zingchart.com/buy/

Answer (score 1):

[Essential Chart for JavaScript](http://js.syncfusion.com/demos/web/#!/azure/chart/line) is also another option to consider. Simple sample application:[link](http://jsplayground.syncfusion.com/Sync_htk3xgkg).

The whole suite of controls is available for free through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) program if you qualify. Note: I work for Syncfusion.

Comment: Since you work for Syncfusion, can you tell us how to use the library with AngularJs (which, after all, is what the question is about). Thanks

Comment: Please refer to [this](http://help.syncfusion.com/js/chart/working-with-data#angularjs-data-binding) documentation link for using the Chart with Angular JS.

Comment: Thanks. Your product looks great and I am very impressed by the extremely generous community license : "Who is eligible?
Individual developers or up to five users at companies with annual gross revenue below $1 million USD"

Answer (score 1):

In my project I used  [D3.js](http://d3js.org/) and it worked very well with AngularJS (v 1.2/1.3).

I created some new directives related to kind of charts I needed. I had no problems.

**EDIT:**

- it has line graphs
- handles a lot of objects
- free

D3.js creates an SVG so the library handles all that SVG can.

Comment: I don't know of a better, more popular, free JS charting library than  D3.js That said, the wrappers available do not cover all chart types, so you might have to do some work there. I just started an AngularJs project and intend to use D3.js so would be grateful if jsDoggy would post some links to how to create new directives for D3.js  Thanx

Comment: Of course, I have also some code to "inject" a D3.js. When I will find a snippet, I'll post it here. Moreover, as @Mawg said, I'll show some example directive.

EDIT: it would be useful: http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/d3-on-angular.html

Answer (score 0):

FusionCharts would be the best suited Javascript library as per your requirements. The library has the [FusionCharts-Angular Directive](https://www.fusioncharts.com/angularjs-charts/#), which will make creating charts in your Angular app a breeze. The library also allows you to customize all the chart attributes to make your chart look the way you want.

You can also read this [quick guide to create charts in Angular](https://www.fusioncharts.com/blog/create-charts-with-angular/).

Would be happy to help if you need any further advice.