# AngularJs charting with treemap (and heatmaps would be nice)

Tags: gratis, charts, angularjs, heatmap

Should this be two questions? Maybe not, just two features of one library.

Does anyone know of an AngularJs library which offers:
 - [TreeMaps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treemapping)
 - Geographical heat maps (with Open Street Maps a bonus)
 - all of the other, more usual, standard charts types
 - [Choropleth maps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Choropleth_map) would be very welcome too

[4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1h2G.jpg) [[image: A tree map, yesterday]][6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSLKN.jpg)

[image] [image]

---

[Update] not that this has anything to do with the question, but 2 minutes after I posted, a friend emailed me this map of the UK - ***drawn from pubs !!***

[[image]]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out [ZingChart](http://www.zingchart.com). They have the ability to create treemaps and maps along with your more common chart types like line, bar, pie... 
There's also a [ZingChart-AngularJS](https://github.com/zingchart/ZingChart-AngularJS) directive that makes it fairly painless to create dynamic charts with AngularJS.

Here are a couple demos of treemaps and maps created with the ZingChart-AngularJS directive:

Map : http://demos.zingchart.com/view/8JE73I88

TreeMap : http://demos.zingchart.com/view/ERU31MKM

While there is no baked in solution to use heatmaps with maps, there is an ability to render maps using [GeoJSON](http://www.zingchart.com/docs/chart-types/maps/#maps__loadGeoJSON), and you can color each region separately - choropleth if you will.

If you have any further questions, don't hesitate to reach out! - I'm a ZingChart Team Member. Check out our [AngularJs pag](https://www.zingchart.com/docs/integrations/angularjs-charts/)e if you need more info. We are also working on a choropleth plugin and should be released pretty soon.

Comment: Looks good, but expensive (I'd rather not have the branding). I will continue to look for a gratis solution & get back to you. Btw, which pricing plan for a single website that **does** require user login?

Comment: If the chart is accessible to the public and for commercial use, then it's a SaaS license. If it is only accessible to your employees, then it would be internal. If you have any more questions, sales@zingchart.com would be your best avenue.

Comment: Thanks (+1). Fine for the big boys, chicken & egg for me. Until I get some sales, I can' afford $2,499, but I can't launch without a solution. Nvm, I will figure something out. Perhaps starting with another solution, then contact you if it takes off.

Comment: Can you give the URL of a sample with branding? Maybe I could go with that until I can afford a SAAS license.

Comment: @Mawg Sure thing : http://demos.zingchart.com/view/MAX9TWAD

Comment: That looks like it would be acceptable.