# Javascript heatmap library

Tags: javascript, heatmap

I love Kibana and their coordinate map:
[image]

I'm looking for a library that does exactly that in JavaScript. Do you know anything?

**Preferred**

- React
- Data IO should be exactly [like Kibana](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/kibana/kibana_working_with_coordinate_map.htm) (best case)
- Free is good - but I would be willing to pay for it

Comment: Please make your question understandable by people who don't use Kibana, by describing with words too. Please read https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2833/140 , edit your question, then ask us to reopen. Thanks! :-)

Comment: Did you look at [D3JS](https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/heatmap_style.html) ? See also answers to [this question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/21614/angularjs-charting-with-treemap-and-heatmaps-would-be-nice)